# AWS: writing from Pandas dataframe to DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue job witten in Python. In it is a large Pandas dataframe - the data contained therein needs to be written to DynamoDB.

I am currently using Glue's "write_dynamic_frame" functionality to achieve this because it copes with issues such as the raising of "500 SlowDown" errors which can sometimes occur when writing large amounts of data in a small period of time.

It is working but the actual writing of data to the database is rather slow (over 2 minutes to write 1,000 records).

My process currently looks like this:

```
my_df = {populate Pandas dataframe...}
table_name = "my_dynamodb_table_name"

# Pandas -> Spark -> DynamicFrame
spark_df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(my_df)
result_df: DynamicFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(spark_df, glue_context, "result_df")

num_partitions: int = result_df.toDF().rdd.getNumPartitions()

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=result_df,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": table_name,
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.5",
        "dynamodb.output.retry": "30"
    }
)
```

Is there any kind of mechanism for the batch writing of data to DynamoDB? I have over a million records that I need to write.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What's your DynamoDB provisioned write throughput, and how large are the records that you're writing?

Comment: @Parsifal Write capacity on target table is currently configured to 10; record size is small: less than 100 characters total per record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as hinted by @Parsifal, was to do with the write throughput of my DynamoDB table. Once this was changed to a more suitable value, data was ingested far more quickly.

Comment: Glad the hint was enough; I was going to do the math this morning. IMO Dynamo isn't a great choice when you need to touch lots of records at a time: each RCU/WCU is cheap, but they add up quickly.

Comment: @Parsifal: I've moved to an "on demand" billing mode as it's more relevant (and cheaper) for my requirements.